# Spring Boot MVC ViewResolver not working, not mapping to internal folder location

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing a spring boot mvc using Spring boot 1.5.6, Java 8. I am trying to use InternalResourceViewResolver for JSP page redirects/path. But it is unable to resolve the path. Could you please let me know what's wrong. Below are the codes

```
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        registry.addViewController("/registration.html");
        registry.addViewController("/logout.html");
        registry.addViewController("/home.html").setViewName("home");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resource/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

    // beans

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        final InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/ui/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver());
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.context-path=/xxxx
spring.profiles.active=dev

logging.level.org.springframework.web=TRACE
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Below is the project structure

[image]

Comment: `bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/ui/");`?

Answer (score 2):

There is another approach in the latest spring version much simpler

Add the below in **Application Properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Also make sure your Project Structure is like this

**`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`**

and under this your files `home.jsp` `login.jsp`

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewResolver, change `bean.setPrefix("/ui/")` to `bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/ui/")` like this:

```
@Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        final InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/ui/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }
```